# How do we integrate $(e^x + 2x)^2$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I need to integrate $$\int(e^x+2x)^2dx.$$

I tried breaking it into $$\int(e^x+2x)(e^x+2x)dx$$ and then integrating by parts, but got stuck at 
$$
\int (e^x + 2x)^2\,dx = 
(e^x+2x)(e^x+x^2)-\int(e^x+2x)(e^x+x^2)dx
$$

Comment: Expand and do it term-by-term.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$\int (e^{2x}+4xe^x+4x^2)dx=0.5e^{2x}+4/3x^3+\int 4xe^xdx$$

by using the by parts method you can integrate the last term

Answer (score 0):

hint: $(a+b)^2= a^2 + 2ab+ b^2$. Then use IBP.

Answer (score 0):

We can expand the square bracket in the integrand to get

\begin{equation*}
\int (4x^2+4e^xx+e^{2x})dx\\
=4\int x^2dx+4\int e^xxdx+\int e^{2x}dx.
\end{equation*}
via the linearity of the integral.

Integrating (using integration by parts for the second integral) gives us

\begin{equation*}
-4e^x+4e^xx+\frac{4x^3}{3}+\frac{e^{2x}}{2}+C\\
=\frac{4x^3}{3}+\frac{e^{2x}}{2}+4e^x(x-1)+C
\end{equation*}
for a constant $C$.$~_{\square}$